# Socket connection aborted after 3 iterations - python

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

I'm developing an application where I want to stream an audio stream to a web page. When I open a connection and send a message, the server and client receive the message `(s.send('Hi'))`. But when I start a loop, my script stops after exact 3 iterations and then quits.

**I noticed that the server throws an `creating default object from empty value` error after the first iteration**

```
import websocket
# https://github.com/liris/websocket-client

HOST = 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080'

s = websocket.create_connection(HOST)

s.send('Hii')

i = 0
while 1:
    i += 1
    print(i)
    s.send(str(i))
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

This is the full error traceback

```
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Redux\Win32\streamingdata.py", line 20, in <module>
    s.send(str(i))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\websocket\__init__.py", line 656, in send
    return self.send_frame(frame)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\websocket\__init__.py", line 680, in send_frame
    l = self._send(data)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\websocket\__init__.py", line 900, in _send
    return self.sock.send(data)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Where does it go wrong? Using pure sockets to a remote listener, the script executes and the server receives the messages. Using websocket it fails. Someone who can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your `time.sleep(0.5)` by `gevent.sleep(0.5)`

As `websocket` is based on `gevent`, you shall prevent using blocking operations.

As the `time.sleep` is blocking one, you are likely blocking sending the data by `webscocket`, which has no chance to communicate during your sleep.

`gevent.sleep` shall give `gevent` greenlet a chance to live.